# Overriding Bootstrap Colors

Tags: html, css, bootswatch

My goal is to take an "almost perfect" (for me) theme and modify it slightly for my needs.  Additionally, I would like to continue to use the CDN for the majority of the work.

I am attempting to use bootswatch and then override the colors defined (primary, secondary, etc.)  The way I understand (clearly wrong) css, I should be able to import css after the bootswatch css and the second would override the first according to [this documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#css-variables).  It does not seem to be working that way:

```css
:root {
    --primary: #78aed5;
    --secondary: #afc7e2;
    --success: #76a443;
    --info: #607aa3;
    --warning: #D47500;
    --danger: #b12949;
    --light: #f8f9fa;
    --dark: #343a40;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.5.0/spacelab/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-5">
        <div class="row mx-0 text-center text-light small rounded">
            <div class="col bg-light text-dark p-1">
                From Override:
            </div>
            <div class="col bg-primary p-1">
                primary
            </div>
            <div class="col bg-secondary p-1">
                secondary
            </div>
            <div class="col bg-success p-1">
                success
            </div>
            <div class="col bg-info p-1">
                info
            </div>
            <div class="col bg-warning p-1">
                warning
            </div>
            <div class="col bg-danger p-1">
                danger
            </div>
            <div class="col bg-light text-dark p-1">
                light
            </div>
            <div class="col bg-dark p-1">
                dark
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-5">
        <div class="row mx-0 text-center text-light small rounded">
            <div class="col bg-light text-dark p-1">
                From Inline Style:
            </div>
            <div class="col p-1" style="background-color:#78aed5;">
                primary
            </div>
            <div class="col p-1" style="background-color:#afc7e2;">
                secondary
            </div>
            <div class="col p-1" style="background-color:#76a443;">
                success
            </div>
            <div class="col p-1" style="background-color:#607aa3;">
                info
            </div>
            <div class="col p-1" style="background-color:#D47500;">
                warning
            </div>
            <div class="col p-1" style="background-color:#b12949;">
                danger
            </div>
            <div class="col text-dark p-1" style="background-color:#f8f9fa;">
                light
            </div>
            <div class="col p-1" style="background-color:#343a40;">
                dark
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is my result:

[image]

I would expect the top css-defined colors to be the same as the lower inline-defined colors, the latter colors being my goal.  That's not the case.

Comment: Of course, the inline style has higher priority and take over what was defined in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `!important`.

```css
:root {
    --primary: #78aed5 !important;
    --secondary: #afc7e2 !important;
    --success: #76a443 !important;
    --info: #607aa3 !important;
    --warning: #D47500 !important;
    --danger: #b12949 !important;
    --light: #f8f9fa !important
    --dark: #343a40 !important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.5.0/spacelab/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-5">
        <div class="row mx-0 text-center text-light small rounded">
            <div class="col bg-light text-dark p-1">
                From Override:
            </div>
            <div class="col bg-primary p-1">
                primary
            </div>
            <div class="col bg-secondary p-1">
                secondary
            </div>
            <div class="col bg-success p-1">
                success
            </div>
            <div class="col bg-info p-1">
                info
            </div>
            <div class="col bg-warning p-1">
                warning
            </div>
            <div class="col bg-danger p-1">
                danger
            </div>
            <div class="col bg-light text-dark p-1">
                light
            </div>
            <div class="col bg-dark p-1">
                dark
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-5">
        <div class="row mx-0 text-center text-light small rounded">
            <div class="col bg-light text-dark p-1">
                From Inline Style:
            </div>
            <div class="col p-1" style="background-color:#78aed5;">
                primary
            </div>
            <div class="col p-1" style="background-color:#afc7e2;">
                secondary
            </div>
            <div class="col p-1" style="background-color:#76a443;">
                success
            </div>
            <div class="col p-1" style="background-color:#607aa3;">
                info
            </div>
            <div class="col p-1" style="background-color:#D47500;">
                warning
            </div>
            <div class="col p-1" style="background-color:#b12949;">
                danger
            </div>
            <div class="col text-dark p-1" style="background-color:#f8f9fa;">
                light
            </div>
            <div class="col p-1" style="background-color:#343a40;">
                dark
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ...only in emergencies (like this)

Comment: I did try that - and indeed when I "run snippet" above, I get the same undesirable results.  I'm not sure if that means I'm having some weird local issue or what.

Comment: locate `:root` in _root.scss

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/
**Please get through this link**

Comment: https://uxplanet.org/how-to-customize-bootstrap-b8078a011203

Comment: I do not want to use sass/scss.  I want to use <style> tags (or a local .css) file to overwrite only the colors.  What's been shared so far doesn;t meet my initial ask that I see - Or I'm not following.